# Why future .isDone() must after the executorService.shutdown()

Tags: java, concurrency

Why future `.isDone()` must after the `executorService.sutdown()`.

This can work:

```
Future<Integer> submit1 = executorService.submit(callable);
executorService.shutdown();
while (submit1.isDone()){
   System.out.println(submit1.get());
}
```

But after I commented this line:

```
Future<Integer> submit1 = executorService.submit(callable);
//executorService.shutdown();
while (submit1.isDone()){
   System.out.println(submit1.get());
}
```

It can't print any result.

Comment: Do you get an exception? What does it tell?

Comment: Thank you ,I have solved this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `submit1.isDone()` in the first place, and definitely not in a `while` loop. As `Future.get()` is a blocking call, you'll get the same behaviour from both when you remove the `while()` part.

The reason you're not getting anything printed in the second case is because the callable hasn't had a chance to finish, so the condition of `while` is false.

What you **can** call after `shutdown()` is `ExecutorService.awaitTermination()`. It will wait up to the given amount of time for all tasks to finish. If you don't want the tasks to finish, you can call `shutdownNow()`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, So , isDone() returns true until I execute the get() ? I think I understant that , It's after the get() ang then isDone() return the true. NOT isDone() returns the true you can get() the result.

Comment: No, `isDone()` returns true if the task is done. You shouldn't be calling it except in special cases. Just remove the whole `while` loop. You don't need to call `isDone()`, just call `get()`. It will block until the result is available.

Comment: OH,I understand that isDone() is not a bloking method ,It's just get() is a bloking method ! Thank you very much ! Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

Because when you call .shutdown() thread's state will change which makes isDone return true. Look at the ThreadPoolExecutor implementation how it changes your threads state:

```
public void shutdown() {
    //...
    tryTerminate();
}


/**
 * Transitions to TERMINATED state if either (SHUTDOWN and pool
 * and queue empty) or (STOP and pool empty). 
 * ....
 * ....
 */
final void tryTerminate() {
....
}
```

And isDone() documentation says that this method **returns true due to normal termination, exception or cancellation**. So:

**1)** You submitted Callable

**2)** You shutDown process, so its state is now TERMINATED

**3)** isDone returns true, you see the out.

In other cases, your Callable never terminates, throws an exception or canceled which makes isDone always return false.

Comment: @Kayaman I wanted to say that tryTerminate function of threadpool will change thread's state by calling termination signall of already submitted threads.

Comment: That's not true either. First of all, you don't submit threads, you submit tasks. When you shutdown a threadpool, it will refuse to accept new tasks, but will finish the old ones. Idle worker threads (if any) are woken up so they can shut down normally. The `tryTerminate()` method shuts down the threadpool if there is no work to be done, but it does not actively kill the worker threads (like `shutdownNow()`.